# How can I change my phone's resolution?

Tags: screen-resolution

I would like to change the resolution of my s4 1080x1920 to 720x1280 not the dpi but the resolution. I have root access and am on android 6.0.1. How can I do this.

I want to do this to see how much battery I can save. Usually my phone last 3 days (normal use) on my custom 7800mah battery without charing but I don't really have much use for an UHD screen so I want to see if it can last longer by lowering the resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using adb, no root required

Use the command `adb shell wm size 720x1280`

## Using phone, root required

Download any Terminal app, such as [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en).
Type the command `su` to enter superuser mode, and then type `wm size 720x1280` into the terminal.

Source: http://www.theandroidsoul.com/change-screen-resolution-adb-android/

Comment: Does this method survive a reboot?

Comment: Yes it does survive a reboot since I have tested it myself. I searched google play and found no apps that could do this. I will make an app myself using this method and upload it to the play store so others like me can have an easy way to change the resolution. Thanks @SSS

Comment: This really does help, usually I lose around 30%/day normal use but  I'm barely losing 20%/day nowadays. For anyone else doing this on s4, the best dpi for 720x1280 in my opinion is 300. I had 480 when resolution was 1080x1920

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to use the dpi route, instead you can modify a system property in `build.prop` file.

Navigate to `/system/build.prop` and find this property name : `persist.dash.max.rep.resolution` under property value put `1280*720`