# After programmatically setting the resolution through an app, how can I make the device remember the new setting?

Tags: applications, terminal

So I'm setting the resolution by editing system files. This has been the only way that works for me. More preciesly I issue this command:

```
echo 1080p60hz > sys/class/display/mode
```

to the device's termninal. This succesfully changes the resolution to 1080p60hz or to a different value if it's issued. However after restart the device returns to its previous resolution.

Does nayone know how to make it remember the new resolution? Probably another file needs to be edited but I haven't found out which.

Comment: I've answered the question of how to change the resolution of a phone before, [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/177664/how-can-i-change-my-phones-resolution/177707#177707). Survives reboots as well.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't really work for me. The device I'm talking about is a TV, and the wm size looks to work mostly on phones. It does produce a change on the TV but it's not equivalent to changing the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Several options:

- modify the boot image accordingly, or
- use `init.d` scripts if your device supports them (if not, there are [some apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_sysmaint#group_1054) to achieve that). Or,
- use an [automation](/tags/automation/info) app to do that on BOOT_COMPLETED (e.g. [tasker](/tags/tasker/info) supports that, e.g. running a script on BOOT_COMPLETED – called "device start" there IIRC).